# Defining a type for lambda expressions in Ocaml

Tags: types, ocaml

For practice, I'm trying to define a type corresponding to lambda-calculus expressions composed of variables, abstractions, and applications. My current best attempt is:

```
type expr = Var of string | Abs of expr * expr | App of expr * expr
```

However, I would like to restrict the first part of an `Abs` to be a `Var`. For instance, I would like this to be an ill-formed expr:

```
Abs(Abs(Var "foo", Var "bar"), Var "bar")
```

but it is currently accepted as valid. I would also like to require that the first part of an `App` be an `Abs`. Is there any way to have the type system enforce these restrictions, or is this pushing it beyond what it was designed to do?

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, `Abs(Var "x", Var "x")` should be considered valid.

Comment: Side note: for many purposes it makes sense to define lambda-terms using de Bruijn indices — this avoids the nastiness of renaming variables when performing substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, you need GADTs to achieve that, which were recently merged into svn trunk.

Here is amateur's example (maybe not fully correct, but it satisfies your requirements) :

```
        OCaml version 3.13.0+dev6 (2011-07-29)

# type _ t =
  | Var : string -> string t
  | Abs : (string t * 'a t) -> (string * 'a) t
  | App : ((string * 'a) t * 'b t) -> ('a -> 'b) t;;
type 'a t =
    Var : string -> string t
  | Abs : (string t * 'b t) -> (string * 'b) t
  | App : ((string * 'c) t * 'd t) -> ('c -> 'd) t
# Abs(Abs(Var "foo", Var "bar"), Var("bar"));;
Error: This expression has type (string * 'a) t
       but an expression was expected of type string t
# App(Var "bar", Abs(Var "foo", Var "bar"));;
Error: This expression has type string t
       but an expression was expected of type (string * 'a) t
# App(Abs(Var "foo", Var "bar"), Var("bar"));;
- : (string -> string) t = App (Abs (Var "foo", Var "bar"), Var "bar")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the type system to directly enforce something like that.  Instead, I would consider defining two types:

```
type variable = Name of string
type expr = Var of variable | Abs of variable * expr | App of expr * expr
```

This is similar to Jeff's answer, but gives you the freedom to change the type used for the defining variables without having to worry about changing it in two places.  Both are valid ways to go about dealing with the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is helpful, but I should have been more specific: I would like `Abs(Var("x"), Var("x"))` to be valid, but, with the code in your answer, it isn't.

Comment: Sure, but Abs(Name("x"),Var(Name("x"))) would be.  It's just a slight change in structure.

Answer (score 2):

[Polymorphic variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#toc36) let you define subtypes of datatypes. The subtypes enforce simple structural constraints.

For example, here's a definition of lambda-terms with polymorphic variants, with a definition of a subtype for head normal forms.

```
type var = [ `Var of string ]

type expr = [
  | var
  | `Abs of var * expr
  | `App of expr * expr
  ]

type irr (*non-head-reducible applications*) = [
  | var
  | `App of irr * expr
  ]
type hnf (*head normal forms*) = [
  | irr
  | `Abs of var * hnf
  ]

let substitution (x : var) (u : expr) : expr -> expr =
  failwith "left as an exercise"

(*Iterated head reductions produce a head normal form*)
let rec head_reductions : expr -> hnf = function
  | #var as x -> x
  | `Abs (x, u) -> `Abs (x, head_reductions u)
  | `App (u, v) ->
      match head_reduction u with
      | #irr as u -> u
      | `Abs (x, w) -> head_reductions (substitution x u (w :> expr))
```

Comment: That seems to accept the example I wanted it to reject: `\`Abs(\`Abs(\`Var "foo", \`Var "bar"), \`Var "bar")`. What am I missing?

Comment: @JoshJordan Polymorphic variant types aren't generative (that's why you can do subtyping with them). What you have is a valid Caml expression. But it's not of type `expr`.

Comment: Thanks. I may have phrased it poorly in my question, but I was hoping to be able to define the type `expr` such the above expression was of that type.

Comment: @JoshJordan So… you've just told me you don't want that expression to be of type `expr, and your want that expression to be of type `expr`. One of the requirements will have to give. Polymorphic variants are definitely a good way of implementing simple structural subtypes. I don't understand what you're after here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you've defined `Abs` to accept two `expr`s and each of those may be `Var`, `Abs` or `App`.

An `Abs`traction should consist of a variable and expression, not two expressions.  A variable is just a string in this case so your `Abs` should consist of a string and expression.

Change it to:

```
Abs of string * expr
```